# Are there any sci-fi novels with multiple human-colonized galaxies?

Tags: novel, space, space-colonization, setting

First of all, sorry for my English. It's not my native language.

All space-themed sci-fi novels I've read deal with human civilizations on the scale from Solar system to whole Milky Way galaxy. Are there any novels, where humans spread to the multiple galaxies?

Thank you!

Comment: I know that this question goes against the "Lists and Recommendations" rule, but there are so few stories that match this idea - I don't know of any, now that I think of it -  I'd be inclined to allow it just for my own curiousity.

Comment: I don't know... Once you have fiction with advanced FTL, spreading to other galaxies can happen. Stargate (TV) had it happen. Some Alastair Reynolds books suggest that it does happen. Interstellar (Movie) talked about the idea. I think the question is too broad, as the list would probably continue to grow as more people contributed lesser-known works. To the OP: To aid you in your search, trying using the term "**intergalactic civilization**". Using those terms, I was quickly able to find at least three novels/series that dealt with intergalactic humanity.

Comment: I know the novels on the *[enderverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender's_Game_(series))* (Ender's game and next ones) had multiples far away colonies, and they went in great detail about how the colonizing worked; but I don't quite remember if they actually extended to *other galaxies*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Lensmen series by E. E. Smith at least one other galaxy is colonized.

Re: [Second Stage Lensmen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Stage_Lensmen)

> The book ends with Kinnison being made Galactic Coordinator of the
>   Second Galaxy and finally marrying Clarissa MacDougall.